# Numbering of equation with fleqn

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

[image]

Hello, I am trying to construct the following equation, however the equation gets numbered thrice, and I need it to get numbered only once. Any way I can achieve that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
logw_{it} = & \ B_0 + B_1edu_t  + B_2exp_t + B_3exp^2_t + D_1urban + D_2married + D_3public\\ &&\\
            &\ +D_4religion + D_5caste +D_6industry + D_6occupation + e_{it} &&
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of `\nonumber` before \\ in an equation, for example (but `split` etc. environments might be better)?. Also use `D_{4\text{religion}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think split is the better option here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I used `\nonumber` and it works absolutely fine. Thanks!

Comment: Also, religion isn't supposed to be a subscript, so `D_{4\text{religion}}` won't work right,

Comment: @KushaVerma: Ok, but religion should not be displayed in italics, in my point of view -- it looks weird there: So `D_{4}\text{religion}` etc.

Comment: Why do you need to use  the`flalign` environment since you load amsmath with option `fleqn`? `align` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the suggestion of @ChristianHupfer, or use `aligned` instead. You don't need `flalign` since you already have set the `fleqn` option for `amsmath`. You may need also to set the `\mathindent` to `0pt` to have the same output as the original setup. Finally, words like `edu`, `urban`, `married`, etc. are not mathematical variables, so these can be typeset  as `\text{..}` or `\mathrm{..}`, or even the older `\rm{..}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{logw}_\mathrm{it} &=  B_0 + B_1\,\mathrm{edu}_t  + B_2\,\exp_t + B_3\,\exp^2_t + D_1\,\mathrm{urban} + D_2\,\mathrm{married} + D_3\,\mathrm{public} \\
          &\phantom{={}} + D_4\,\mathrm{religion} + D_5\,\mathrm{caste} +D_6\,\mathrm{industry} + D_6\,\mathrm{occupation} + e_\mathrm{it}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Good answer, but worth noting that the `fl` in `flalign` does not mean the sane thing as the `fl` in the `fleqn` option. `fleqn` is *f*lush *l*eft equations and `flalign` is *f*ull *l*length alignment.

Comment: Also, I think it is better not to talk about `\rm`, specially for beginners. By the way, if I'm not wrong, it should be surrounded by braces: `{\rm }`.